# Distance between two Polar-Coordinates

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I choose two Points in Berlin with the coordinates:

```
  1: lat: 52.511206  long: 13.546486
  2: lat: 52.527501  long: 13.319206
```

With an online tool I got the distance between the two points with around: `15.48` kilometers, what seems to be correct.

Now I **tried to calculate the distance** by my own.
In my script it says that its possible to transform polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates with the origin of the earths middle point:

```
 x: sin(lat) * cos(long)
 y: sin(lat) * sin(long)
 z: cos(long)
```

Because the earth is round and not a plane, to calculate the distance with formula is not 100% exact but for this little distance it should work.

So I inserted my numbers and got this results:

```
 1: 0.566225110618    0.52677679361     0.72975322153
 2: 0.43345006608     0.64846301808     0.55692671558
```

With the euclidian distance I got: **0.24752019375**

**So the numbers for me seem not be coorect**

How do I have to use the forumla? Do I have to multiply the result with something? **Thanks**

Comment: Are you trying to calculate a distance along the earth's surface, or the Euclidean distance (which goes through the planet)?

Comment: Euclidean distance. The difference for this little distance on the Earth shoudn't be too big

Comment: I suspect your calculator is in radian mode, but you inputted degrees.  There is no way that the x/y/z coordinates should be that different for two points so close together.  Also, where is the radius of the earth in your calculations?

Comment: @vadim123 Can say me the correct formula? I thought maybe I have to multiply my result with the radius of the earth? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Earth is not in a sphere form, instead it looks like an ellipsoid, squeezed between North and South Poles.

The latitude-longitude pairs are calculated considering the flattening coefficient ($f$) and eccentricity ($e_1$, $e_2$).

Here the detailed calculation method is:

http://www.colorado.edu/geography/gcraft/notes/datum/gif/xyzllh.gif